# What is the opposite expression of "a broken spoon": "a normal spoon" or "a good spoon"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

Ok, say, you child is hold a broken spoon like in this picture

[image]

Then you say "**Sweetie, throw this broken spoon away, I will give you the good one / normal one**"

What is the opposite expression of "**a broken spoon**": "**a normal spoon**" or "**a good spoon**"?

If we say "**a good spoon**", then people may think of its quality and besides "**a bad spoon**" may not be broken.

Also, "**a normal spoon**" sounds weird.

Comment: Had you considered "unbroken"?

Comment: If the child were very small, I might prefer to say "a spoon that isn't broken", rather than 'an unbroken spoon', which is a little complex and formal for a small child. I expect that the situation chosen is an imaginary one, invented for a language question, but I would never give a small child a piece of fragile brittle plastic cutlery like the one in the picture, for safety reasons.

Comment: Yes, “unbroken spoon” is unnecessary complex and formal for children (and indeed for any informal usage). I’d just expect to hear **“a new spoon”** since it is perfectly obvious that the old spoon is broken and the new one won’t be.

Comment: You could also talk of a 'spoon with a broken handle' and 'a spoon with a handle that isn't broken'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, in its normal state, a spoon is unbroken, I would not personally add any adjective to describe the replacement spoon, and would think the following would be a more natural turn of phrase:

> Throw this broken spoon away, I'll get you another one.

In normal conversation, it would not be necessary to explicitly state that the new spoon will be good/normal/unbroken, nor would it be necessary to clarify that *"another one"* is not referring to another broken spoon.